# Not able to handle ORA-01476: “divisor is equal to zero”

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a simple procedure in which I am using a cursor to fetch some valid items. Using these valid items, I am obtaining some values and doing a calculation on them. The code looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE p_loadanalyse
IS
qty_1       NUMBER;
qty_2      NUMBER := 0;
V_CALC      Number := 0;
Item_No_Rec valid_items%Rowtype;

CURSOR c_validitem
IS
SELECT DISTINCT item_no
From valid_items A;

Begin

For Item_No_Rec In C_Validitem

Loop

SELECT ROUND(SUM(Qty1),2)
INTO qty_1 -- FCST_QTY_PCD
FROM qty1_table
WHERE item_No        = item_No_rec.item_No;

SELECT SUM(Qty2)
INTO qty_2
FROM qty2_table
WHERE A.Item_No       = Item_No_Rec.Item_No;

V_CALC      := (QTY_1  /QTY_2)*100;

Dbms_Output.Put_Line('deviation' ||V_Deviation); 

END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
qty_1 := 0;
qty_2 := 0;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_output.put_line('There is an error');
END;
```

The problem is obviously in the statement `V_CALC      := (QTY1  /QTY2)*100;` when QTY2 is 0. So I try to handle it like:

```
 IF QTY_2 <> 0 THEN
  V_CALC      := (QTY_1  /QTY_2)*100;
 ELSE
  V_CALC      := 0;
 END IF;
```

This surprisingly hangs my SQL Developer when I try to compile the procedure. And gives a `timeout occurred while trying to lock object` after 10-11 mins. What I did was not rocket science and Oracle should have behaved the way I wanted, but instead I had to think and try all other ways of handling this divide by zero thingy like:

- Including `EXCEPTION WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN QTY_2 := 0;`
- Using `CASE` instead of `IF`

After trying all permutations and combinations for 3 days, I am out of ideas and reasons and still with no output. Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: When the `create or replace` statement "hangs", this usually means the procedure is currently being run from a different session.

Comment: There is just one session.

Comment: If, you are the only one using it, You can try it out in SQL*Plus, sometimes SQL Developer may throw these errors, due to internal bugs. also, trying after reconnecting to the database should work which clears all the persistent data.

Comment: Does the procedure still hang if you remove the line `V_CALC      := (QTY_1  /QTY_2)*100;`?

Comment: Unrelated, I think, but you don't need to declare your row type record `Item_No_Rec` that you use in the `FOR` loop. The nice thing about `FOR` loops is that it automatically declares the record for you.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt SQL developer is hanging because of your if statement or a divide by zero error.  You may want to see if other users are using the procedure or if there are any processes in the database that need to be killed.

This can be shown if you can recreate the procedure but with another name..

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. And I am the only one using it.

Comment: Is everything else working fine in this database?  Have you tried rebooting the computer?  lol its a very odd error.

Answer (score 0):

Close the procedure before recreating it. SQL Developer block opened procedures.

Additionaly, try create it with different name of package/procedure.

And to be sure it's not zero division problem, create procedure empty...